# How to set up router to always redirect users to a website?

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I'm trying to set up a Linksys E2500 to only allow access to two webpages. Both pages are on the same domain (e.g. www.foo.com and blog.foo.com). I've flashed my router with DD-WRT firmware for greater configuration options, but I'm in over my head.

The ideal set up would be to have users be able to access the two websites if they type the addresses in directly. If they type any other address, then they are redirected to www.foo.com. However, an acceptable set up would be for users to be shown a "blocked" page when attempting to access a non-whitelisted site or for the connection to non-whitelisted sites to simply fail.

I tried using DNSMasq, but I cannot seem to access the whitelisted websites when using their IP. I also attempted to set up NoCatSplash, but was unable to get it working (I was never redirected to the specified page). However, I admit that this may have been due to an incorrect set up.

To be clear, I don't want users to be redirected to a sign in page (a captive portal), I want them to only have access to the two websites I specify.